# expires_in value in answer wso2 api manager to authorize request

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod with the value 680400. Configured so, the acces_token is in fact valid for a week which is exactly what I need.
But when I make a request:

```
https://server01:9443/oauth2/authorize
```

there is a redirect to

```
https://server01/src-osdk/#access_token=28352467a413806ccb5ee8d4ccc0f382&state=2cea70c1-b0d9-4547-ab36-f1bd411698b2&expires_in=3600.
```

As you can see, expires_in=3600 while I expected it to be the same as it is set in the configuration above. The client library treats this value as the token validity time and behaves accordingly thus discregarding that the access_token will be valid for a much longer time.

In case I do not misinterpret the meaning of the "expires_in" parameter, this looks like a bug.

P.S. I use wso2 api manager - not identity server

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find out how to have the correct value in the expires_in parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the 'UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod' configuration element in identity.xml to change user token expiration time,instead 'AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod' element.

Thanks;

/Lalaji

Comment: I see in databases true value - 68040000, and token is really valid and not regenerate these time. Problem is only in answer to request, not in logic.